# Search and FInd a word/Letter in a WebView

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, ios4

I have a Webview in which i display the html pages,there i have placed a search bar, Now I have to find a letter or a  particular word that i type in the search bar, those letters or word should be highlighted with different color in the present html page. 
  Help me out

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have done this in Tableview, but i am unable to do in the webview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can search for those keyword inside your html document that you are showing on the webview .Now you can reload the webview with new html formed by replacing keyword string with <>keyword<> string .

Comment: Hi Ali Thank u for the answer can u give any sample code for it

Comment: hi ., you can try like this [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[@"keyword" withString:@"<b>keyword</b>"];
     [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];